# What is the difference between the two for loops?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

I had a question which I hope someone is able to clarify for me. What is the difference between the following two for loops?

```
c = zeros(16,10);
for k = 1:10
    c(1,k) = log(k+1) - log(k);
    for n = 1:15
        **c**(n+1,k) = 1./n - k*(c(n,k));
    end
end
```

%%%%%

```
c = zeros(16,10);
for k = 1:10
    c(1,k) = log(k+1) - log(k);
    for n = 1:15
        **A**(n+1,k) = 1./n - k*(c(n,k));
    end
end
```

A lot of times I find myself trying different areas when its simply a result of a specification of matrix. In the 2nd code of the for loop, it does create a new matrix also but what are the difference in terms of the calculations ?

Thanks

Comment: The capital C is very hard to notice; you may want to use 1/ a different variable name for clarity, and 2/ point explicitly to the difference.

Comment: @Evert edited to make C more distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like noted, the capital `C` in the second program is very hard to notice. So I'm going to call it `A`.

After running the first program, say you have `c1` matrix (`c` with all the calculations done).

The second program will produce 2 matrices `A` and `c2`. This `c2` only has the first row of of the first `c1`, the rest of `c2` is 0's. `A` will have the rest of `c1`, except for its first row, which is all 0's.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes makes much more sense. Thanks